# Problem connecting with external MQTT broker

Tags: python-3.x, linux, ubuntu, mqtt, payload

I am using Ubuntu mate on the Pine A64+ 1Gb, I have installed paho mqtt library with python3, I tested library by creating local mosquito server and it is working fine. Now I need to connect to external broker having username and password, I tried with following code but it didn't worked for me. With this I am not even able to connect to the broker.

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import time
broker_address = "121.242.232.175.xip.io"
port = 1883

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    if rc==0:
        client.connected_flag = True
        print("connected OK Returned code=",rc)
    else:
        print("Bad connection Returned code=",rc)

mqtt.Client.connected_flag = False

client = mqtt.Client("SWAHVACAHU00000600")
client.username_pw_set(username="#####",password="#####")
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.loop_start()
client.connect(broker_address, port)
#while not client.connected_flag:
#   print("inthe while")
#   time.sleep(1)

client.loop_stop()
client.publish("pine", "Hello from Pinr A64",0)
client.disconnect()
```

I am checking on hivemqtt using as websocket client and subscribing to the same topic.

Comment: In what way does this code fail? Does it print an error message? Does it just hang?

Comment: @larsks No it doesn't hang neither it gives any error message. It sits inside the loop for client.connect

Comment: Have you verified that you can connect to the remote mqtt server using, e.g., `mosquitto_sub`?

Comment: @larsks yes I have verified remote connection it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Check again what `loop_start()` does:

> These functions implement a threaded interface to the network loop. Calling loop_start() once, before or after connect*(), runs a thread in the background to call loop() automatically. This frees up the main thread for other work that may be blocking. This call also handles reconnecting to the broker. Call loop_stop() to stop the background thread

[paho-mqtt](https://pypi.org/project/paho-mqtt/#network-loop)

That means that you start a thread which frequently handles all your networking actions (also sending your connection attempt). In your code you immediateley stop this thread again by calling `loop_stop()` - so there is a high chance that your connection attempt wasn't even send out.

In addition your main program terminates right after `client.disconnect()` without any delay - so the networking thread (if running) has absoluetly no time to deal anything at all

I recommend to restructure your code so your actions are properly timed and connection is closed after all work is done:

```
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    if rc==0:
        print("Connected.")
        client.publish("mytopic/example", "")
    else:
        print("Connection refused, rc=",rc)

def on_disconnect(client, userdata, rc):
    print ("Disconnected")
    if rc != 0:
        # otherwise loop_forever won't return
        client.disconnect()

def on_publish(client, userdataq, mid):
    print ("Message delivered - closing down connection")
    client.disconnect()


print ("Program started")

client = mqtt.Client("MyClient")
client.username_pw_set(username=user,password=pw)
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_disconnect = on_disconnect
client.on_publish = on_publish

client.connect(broker_address, port)

client.loop_forever()

print("Program finished")
```

The blocking loop `loop_forever()` automatically returns if `disconnect()` is called. When using `loop_start()` / `loop_stop()` you need a loop by your own in order to prevent your program from terminating and you also have to handle when to break the loop and when to close the networking thread.

Also consider putting `client.connect()` within a `try...except` block